# How I can change the border color of the bars in a bokeh histogram?

Tags: python, html, visualization, bokeh

**Objective:** to change the border color of a Bokeh histogram bar from default black.

Below is an actual snippet from a Bokeh histogram:

[image]

The black lines highlighted above are what I am aiming to change to any other color besides black.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't provided any code (you should *always* provide sample code when asking for help). So it's not actually possible to knowk whether you are using the old (and deprecated and removed) `bokeh.charts.Histogram` or not. If that is the case, first things first: **stop using it immediately**. The old `bokeh.charts` API is completely unmaintained at this point. It is a dead end.

Either way, you can create a histogram in Bokeh using the stable ad supported `bokeh.plotting` API, in which case styling is styling is accomplished in the same general manner for all glyphs, [as described in the User's Guide documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html).

Here is a complete example:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df

from numpy import histogram, linspace

x = linspace(0,250,200)

p = figure(plot_height=300)

hist, edges = histogram(df.hp, density=True, bins=20)
p.quad(top=hist, bottom=0, left=edges[:-1], right=edges[1:], alpha=0.4,

       # same technique and properties for every Bokeh Glyph
       line_color="red", line_width=2)

output_file("hist.html")

show(p)
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, if you are looking for a very high level API with a built in "Histogram Plot" type function, check out out HoloViews: http://holoviews.org/ It is a very high level API built on top of Bokeh and is actively maintained by a team of people.